# Success in using Android to control an external monitor via HDMI

Tags: java, android, display, hdmi

just wondering if anyone has managed physically to use an Android tablet  to control an external screen via and HDMI cable. The Android tablet should have the Presentation APIs, so a version > 4.2m and an HDMI (or mini HDMI) port.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html

So far we have tested with a tablet that has Android v5.1.1 and a mini HDMI port, but as soon as we connect the external monitor, the tablet monitor shuts off (but it is still responsive to touch) and all the output goes to the external monitor.
The tablet is a HannsPad Titan2 13.3 inches.

So we are still stuck on the physical setup. It this does not work at least with mirroring, how can we be expected to start tinkering with the presentation API?

So we are looking for confirmation from other coders that the setup is at least physically been done and tested at least once..

Thanks
W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as soon as we connect the external monitor, the tablet monitor shuts off (but it is still responsive to touch) and all the output goes to the external monitor

That was an incompatible and unfortunate choice made by your device manufacturer. The screen should remain on. You might rummage through Settings to see if there is a way to configure this behavior, or contact the device manufacturer for support.

> The tablet is a HannsPad Titan2 13.3 inches.

Buy a better brand next time.

> It this does not work at least with mirroring, how can we be expected to start tinkering with the presentation API?

Buy a different tablet. Note that (micro-)HDMI connectors seem to be less common, though some tablets might also support MHL or SlimPort.

Or, in Settings > Developer options, choose "Simulate secondary display" to give yourself a floating window that serves as a fake external display that `Presentation` can drive ([except perhaps on Android O](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37908297)). For development purposes, this works for light testing.

> So we are looking for confirmation from other coders that the setup is at least physically been done and tested at least once.

I have never used that tablet. However, the `Presentation` APIs work just fine. For example, I was just updating [my CWAC-Presentation library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation) yesterday, and part of that testing included trying my demo app on a Nexus 10 connected to a micro-projector via its micro-HDMI connector.

Comment: Hello, thanks @CommonsWare, we are starting to suspect this is a shitty device. But our customer required a huge tablet with HDMI output and Android, and this was as far as our googling went, the only one available.. 

Now unfortunately we are switching to a raspberryPi+Android solution.
Thanks